# MQL5: How to Rank an Array's values

Tags: arrays, mql5, ranking-functions

I used R and the rank function to create the following ranks for the original var `x`:

```
x average first last random max min
3     4.5     4    5      5   5   4
1     1.5     1    2      2   2   1
4     6.0     6    6      6   6   6
1     1.5     2    1      1   2   1
5     8.0     7    9      9   9   7
9    11.0    11   11     11  11  11
2     3.0     3    3      3   3   3
6    10.0    10   10     10  10  10
5     8.0     8    8      7   9   7
3     4.5     5    4      4   5   4
5     8.0     9    7      8   9   7
```

I am struggling to implement the `min`-version in MQL5. First, you probably need to sort the Array but you need to take care of the original order. How the ranks are assigned manually is quite logical but I have no clue how to implement this in MQL5.

Comment: Do you have any idea why you need the original order and what the rank is? You can use `ArrayMinimum(int&array[])` function(keeping the rest two parameters as default) to get the index of the minimal value